# Toggle Classes in between two divs in different files using buttons in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly New to React and stuck on a problem with how to import tags from other JS files in react.js to add classes and functionality. I used useRef() but it's a little confusing

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import GPS from '../resources/gps.png'
import cloud from '../resources/Shower.png'
import location from '../resources/location.png'
export default function Today()
{ 
    return(
        <div>
        <div ref={clicked} className="Today">
            <div className="Nav">
                <button  className="Search">Seach for places</button>
                <img className="gps" src={GPS}></img>
            </div>
            <div className="information">
                <img className="cloud" src={cloud}></img>
                <h1>15<sub>°C</sub></h1>
                <h3>Shower</h3>
                <p> <span>Today</span> <span> Fri, 11 Dec</span> </p>
                <div className="location">
                <img className="loca" src={location} ></img>
                <p>New Delhi</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the first file in which I want to import the "find-location" of another file

```
import React from "react";
import Cross from '../resources/cross.png'

export default function Search(props)
{
    return (
        <div className="find-location ">
        <button className="cross-button"><img className="cross" src={Cross}></img></button> 
        <div className="search--tab">
         <input className="field" placeholder=" search location"></input>
         <button className="clicked">Search</button>
        </div>
     </div>
    )
}
```

I tried useRef and successfully imported from 2nd to first but was unable to do vice versa

Comment: Can you add your code to `codesandbox`? https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-feather-t2heml